# Mysql "source" command: wrong exit code?

Tags: mysql, linux

Why does the mysql "source" command return the wrong exit code? Is there a way to make it fail properly?

(Note that I'm purposely trying to return an error here)

Without source:

```
$ mysql -e "use mydatabase; select asdf from mytable;"
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'asdf' in 'field list'
$ echo $?
1
```

With "source" (file.sql contains the "select..." request)

```
$ mysql -e "use mydatabase; source /absolute/path/to/file.sql"
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1 in file: '/absolute/path/to/file.sql': Unknown column 'asdf' in 'field list
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Which wrong exit code are you referring to?

Comment: Using `source` inside the `-e` command is the long way around. Use file redirection and specify the database name on the command line instead:  `mysql mydatabase < /absolute/path/to/file.sql`

Comment: Or do you have a specific reason you want to use `source`?

Comment: @pal4life: I'm referring to the bash exit code.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: well, good suggestion :) no specific reasons to use source here excepted "legacy code". I feel a little dumb not having thought about it in the first place

Comment: I don't know that the bash exit code will be any different, though I would hope it is.

Comment: It is indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The exit status of the `source` command appears to reflect whether it was able to read the file or not, rather than the success of the queries within it.

```
barmar@dev:~$ mysql -e 'source /nonexistent/file'
ERROR at line 1: Failed to open file '/nonexistent/file', error: 2
barmar@dev:~$ echo $?
1
```